# androidアプリが64bitCPUに対応しているかの確認方法

Tags: android

作成したAndroidアプリが64bitCPUに対応しているかどうかは、「ネイティブコードが含まれているかどうか」のみで判断できると理解しています。
まずこの理解は合っていますか？ほかに考慮することはありますか？

アプリにネイティブコードを含むかどうかは、AndroidStudioのAnalyzeAPKを実行した結果に拡張子.soのファイルがあるかどうかで判断していいですか？(参照： https://cpoint-lab.co.jp/article/201907/10595/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 作成したAndroidアプリが64bitCPUに対応しているかどうかは、「ネイティブコードが含まれているかどうか」のみで判断できると理解しています。
> まずこの理解は合っていますか？

大雑把には正しい理解です。より正確に表現するなら：

- Androidアプリがネイティブコードを1つも含まない場合：（自動的に）64bit CPUに対応します。
- Androidアプリがネイティブコードを1つ以上含む場合：

  - `lib/arm64-v8a`ディレクトリ以下に`*.so`ファイルが配置されているなら、ARMアーキテクチャの64bit CPUに対応します。
  - `lib/x86_64`ディレクトリ以下に`*.so`ファイルが配置されているなら、Intel x86アーキテクチャの64bit CPUに対応します。

公式サイトdeveloper.android.comの記事「[64ビットアーキテクチャのサポート](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit?hl=JA)」もあわせて参照ください。